# I would like there to be text on the first image but not the second - swipable

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to accomplish this: I would like there to be text on the first image, but after that I do not want there to be. Everything I commented out is how I am doing it originally, but changed so it could be viewed for you guys. Please make note of that as it might change the insight I receive. Right now I am getting no display of text at all.

Also, if the carousel in there adds too much distraction I can take it out.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const height = width * 0.6;

const images = [
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2249602/pexels-photo-2249602.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-sergio-souza-2249602.jpg&fm=jpg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3178881/pexels-photo-3178881.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-andrew-neel-3178881.jpg&fm=jpg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4946412/pexels-photo-4946412.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-maria-orlova-4946412.jpg&fm=jpg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4911060/pexels-photo-4911060.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-cottonbro-4911060.jpg&fm=jpg',
];

//this is the array I noramlly use. 
//const images = [
//   {id : "1", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder1.jpg'), text: "Test"},
//   {id : "2", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder2.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "3", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder3.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "4", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder4.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "5", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder5.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "6", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder6.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "7", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder7.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "8", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder8.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//   {id : "9", uri: require('../../assets/placeholder9.jpg'), /*text: "Test"*/},
//]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    active: 0,
  };

  change = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const slide = Math.ceil(
      nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width
    );
      if (slide !== this.state.active) {
        this.setState({ active: slide });
    }
    
  };
  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 3, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ScrollView
          pagingEnabled
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={this.change}
          style={{ width, height }}>
 
          {
            images.map((image, index) => (
            <ImageBackground
              key={index}
              source={{uri: image}}
              //Normally, I would not have key and source would be like this
              //source={item.uri}
              style={{ width, height: '100%', resizeMode: 'cover' }}>
                  <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 25 }}>      
                     <Text style = {this.state.active === 0 ? <Text>Placeholder</Text> : null , styles.Name}> </Text>  
                 <Text style = {this.state.active === 0 ? <Text>Another Placeholder</Text> : null , styles.Name}> </Text>        
</View>
             </ImageBackground>
             ))
             }

        </ScrollView>

           <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, alignSelf: 'center',}}>
               {
                  images.map((i, k) => (
                    <Text style={k == this.state.active ? styles.activeCorousel : styles.carousel}> 
                      ⬤
                    </Text>
                  ))}
            </View>

     </View>
   </View>
      
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  carousel: {
    color: '#888',
    fontSize: width / 35,
    opacity: .5
  },
  activeCorousel: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: width / 35,
  },
    Name: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 40,
    paddingLeft: 20
        },      
});
```

Feel free to copy my code into snack.expo.io.

Comment: Just to get this clear, you want an image with text only for the first item of the array, right? For all the other items there should only be an image, right?

Comment: You are exactly correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use conditional JSX to render only if the index is equal to 0.

```
images.map((image, index) => (
  <ImageBackground
    key={index}
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={{ width, height: '100%', resizeMode: 'cover' }}
  >
    {index === 0 && (
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 25 }}>      
        <Text>Placeholder</Text> 
      </View>
    )}
  </ImageBackground>
))
```

Also, your conditional styling:

```
<Text style = {this.state.active === 0 ? <Text>...
```

does not make any sense at all; `style` attribute does not support JSX, just only React Native valid styling props.